# Does XML Schema Inheritance work in the same sense as OOP Inheritance?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I am working on a schema file that I intend to use with JAXB for a project of mine.  In Java, I have the following sort of code structure

```
public interface Condition {
   ...
}

public class AndCondition implements Condition {
   public AndCondition(List<Condition> conditions){
      ...
   }
}

public class StateCondition implements Condition {
   public StateCondition(Item item, String attributeName, String attributeValue){
      ...
   }
}
```

Naturally I have other objects in my code which rely on having a Condition object

```
public class Action{
   List<Item> targets;
   List<Item> tools;
   Condition condition;
   ...
}
```

My question is, if I define in my XML Schema a complexType and extend them:

```
<xs:element name="Condition">
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="StateCondition">
   <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Condition">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Item" />
            <xs:element name="ATTRIB" type="AttributeType" />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
   </xs:complexContent>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="AndCondition">
   <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Condition">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Condition" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
   </xs:complexContent>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Item">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TARGETS">
         <xs:element ref="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded />
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="TOOLS">
         <xs:element ref="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded />
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element ref="Condition" />
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

Will I achieve the same sort of idea?  In which I mean, if I create an XML file that holds one AndCondition, will it satisfy the validator?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself after a bit of reading.  Hopefully this question will come to use for someone else.  The resource to read is [here](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_13-Defining-Subtypes.html), which defines how JAXB handles extending base types in XML Schema definitions.

Quick and short, yes, JAXB views extension in schema as inheritance in Java.

Answer (score 0):

[xs:extension](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp)'s base attribute must reference a type.  This is a built-in type, simple type you define with a name, or a complex type you define with a name.  So you could define types that correspond to your elements in the example (ConditionType, StateConditionType, etc.) and apply them to your named attributes.  Then in your base schema, you can define a [xs:choice](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp) to insure that you choose at least one of the elements you define.